# google analytics v4 integration to my android app

Tags: android, google-analytics, google-analytics-firebase

I have followed everything according to document provided by google, but am facing some issues, I have added `google-services.json` in root directory i.e in app.

Error:

> Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugGoogleServices'.
>    No matching client found for package name 'com.google.samples.quickstart.analytics'

am getting this error. do help am working on android studio.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try resolving the issue by adding the following line in the dependencies of the project-level build.gradle:

`classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:1.5.0'`

Comment: I added it, is R.xml.global_tracker is auto generated. Am confused about this, please guide me. how to get this global_tracker file.

Comment: @aadhagupta you have to add global_track.xml to your res/xml/ folder youself. Please see this link for global_track.xml http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33637999/google-analytics-v4-string-xml-configuration-name-not-recognized-ga-trackingi

Answer (score 0):

Now Use like this in build.gradle:
`com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:8.4.0`

And follow this instructions:
[Add Analytics to Your Android App](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v4/)

You can also generate configuration file from there 
Follow the title: [Add the configuration file to your project](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v4/#get-config)

Hope it will helpful for you.

**EDIT:**

Also please check if your **build.gradle** contains this line then remove it:

`apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'`

Comment: I have done as it is but still am getting this error. i followed the https://github.com/googlesamples/google-services/blob/master/android/analytics/app/src/main/java/com/google/samples/quickstart/analytics/MainActivity.java this code, I added the global_tracker.xml also, added google-services.json also.

Answer (score 0):

Seriously, Google should really make GA easier for all of us!!

Here's how I manage to get it work on `buildToolsVersion '23.0.3'` with `com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.4.0`

## app build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion '23.0.3'

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId 'com.xxx.xxx'
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName '1.0'
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    sourceSets {
        main {
            res.srcDirs =
                    [
                            'src/main/res/layouts/account',
                            'src/main/res/layouts/drawer',
                            'src/main/res/layouts/ntd',
                            'src/main/res/layouts/main',
                            'src/main/res/layouts',
                            'src/main/res'
                    ]
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.3.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.3.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.4.0'        
}
```

- I actually remove this line `compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:8.4.0'` and it still works.

## top-level build.gradle

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.0.0'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:2.0.0-alpha6'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

GAV4 is really a pain in the axx, so I would also like to remind you somethings.

## google-services.json

[Official GAV4 Document](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v4/#set-up-your-project)  tells you to generate `google-services.json` and put it under your `project/app/` folder. However, it never says anything about this message.

> AnalyticsService not registered in the app manifest. Hits might not be
>   delivered reliably. See *google short url* for instructions.

And I end up find the solution here [analyticsservice-not-registered-in-the-app-manifest-error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30154057/analyticsservice-not-registered-in-the-app-manifest-error)

## json with flavor

If you are building a complex project, you might also want to use flavor for different json files. See the flavor config here [google-services-json-for-different-productflavors?lq=1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30772201/google-services-json-for-different-productflavors?lq=1)

## xml app tracker

Yet, you would still have a hard time using xml to configure the tracker, so I also advice you to see this thread [google-analytics-v4-string-xml-configuration-name-not-recognized-ga-trackingi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33637999/google-analytics-v4-string-xml-configuration-name-not-recognized-ga-trackingi)

## google_app_id

Finally, you would still see this message

> GoogleService failed to initialize, status: 10, Missing an expected
>   resource: 'R.string.google_app_id' for initializing Google services.
>   Possible causes are missing google-services.json or
>   com.google.gms.google-services gradle plugin.

which you could find some discussion here [googleservice-failed-to-initialize](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34365369/googleservice-failed-to-initialize)

In `strings.xml`, I do add `R.string.google_app_id` which is your project id in google api console, but I think it would still work even without it. I just want to get rid of that message from the log.

Wish you all good luck!